# Make a loop to scrape a website to create multiple dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I'm working on a project where I can see two ways to potentially solve my problem. I'm scraping a webpage by using a loop to save the each page locally as a HTML file.  The problem I'm having is when I try to select on the files in my local folder they are basically blank pages.  I'm not sure why.  I've used this same code on other sites for this project with success.

This is the code I'm using.

```r
#scrape playoff teams for multiple seasons and saved html to local folder
for(i in 2002:2021){
    playoff_url <- read_html(paste0("https://www.espn.com/nfl/stats/player/_/season/",i,"/seasontype/3"))
    playoff_stats <- playoff_url %>%
    write_html(paste0("playoff",i,".HTML"))
    }
```

My second option is to scrape individual seasons into a data frame, but I would like to do it in  a loop, and to not have to run this code 20 different times. I also don't want  to continually scrape data from the site every time I run the code. It doesn't matter if all the data is in 1 large data frame for all 20 seasons or 20 separate ones.  I can export the code to a local file then import it when I need it.

```r
#read in code for playoff QBs from ESPN and added year column
playoff_url <- read_html("https://www.espn.com/nfl/stats/player/_/season/2015/seasontype/3")
play_QB2015 <-playoff_url %>%  
html_nodes("table") %>% 
html_table()

#combine list from QB playoff data to convert to dataframe
play_QB2015 <- c(play_QB2015[[1]], play_QB2015[[2]])

# Convert list to dataframe using data.frame()
play_QB2015 <- data.frame(play_QB2015)
play_QB2015$Year = 2015
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what happens to your files, but first downloading and storing with httr2 and then parsing saved files with rvest works fine for me (sorry for overused tidyverse ..) :

```r
library(fs)
library(dplyr)
library(httr2)
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

dest_dir <- path_temp("playoffs")
dir_create(dest_dir)

years <- 2002:2012
# collect all years to a list
playoff_lst <- map(
  set_names(years), 
  ~ {
    dest_file <- path(dest_dir, str_glue("{.x}.html"))
    # only download if local copy is not present
    if (!file_exists(dest_file)){
      request(str_glue("https://www.espn.com/nfl/stats/player/_/season/{.x}/seasontype/3")) %>% 
        req_perform(dest_file)
      }
    read_html(dest_file) %>% 
      html_elements("table") %>% 
      html_table() %>% 
      bind_cols()
    }
  )
```

Results:

```r
names(playoff_lst)
#>  [1] "2002" "2003" "2004" "2005" "2006" "2007" "2008" "2009" "2010" "2011"
#> [11] "2012"
head(playoff_lst$`2002`)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 17
#>      RK Name      POS      GP   CMP   ATT `CMP%`   YDS   AVG `YDS/G`   LNG    TD
#>   <int> <chr>     <chr> <int> <int> <int>  <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <dbl> <int> <int>
#> 1     1 Rich Gan… QB        3    73   115   63.5   841   7.3    280.    50     7
#> 2     2 Brad Joh… QB        3    53    98   54.1   670   6.8    223.    71     5
#> 3     3 Tommy Ma… QB        2    51    89   57.3   633   7.1    316.    40     5
#> 4     4 Steve Mc… QB        2    48    80   60     532   6.7    266     39     3
#> 5     5 Jeff Gar… QB        2    49    85   57.6   524   6.2    262     76     3
#> 6     6 Donovan … QB        2    46    79   58.2   490   6.2    245     42     1
#> # … with 5 more variables: INT <int>, SACK <int>, SYL <int>, QBR <lgl>,
#> #   RTG <dbl>

dir_tree(dest_dir)
#> ... /RtmpcjLFJe/playoffs
#> ├── 2002.html
#> ├── 2003.html
#> ├── 2004.html
#> ├── 2005.html
#> ├── 2006.html
#> ├── 2007.html
#> ├── 2008.html
#> ├── 2009.html
#> ├── 2010.html
#> ├── 2011.html
#> └── 2012.html
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I will try the code when I get a chance and let you know.

Comment: Thank you for the help it worked.  I found out something interesting.  While I was trying to understand the code you posted I looked into the local folder where all the files were saved and they opened a blank page as well, but I knew your code was fine so I went back and tried my code and it worked.  Since the local html files didn't behave like the 6 or seven other sites I scraped I didn't bother trying the other code I had to loaded it back into R.  Now I have two ways of doing.

Comment: @Darnell, you checked saved html files though your browser and those rendered as blank pages? It's quite common that resources required to render the page can't be loaded once host and path is changed (i.e you open  your local copy).